# Improve AngularJs ng-class Performance with lots of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im looking to improve the speed of ng-class or find and alternative way to do it, because it takes too long to load when it have to manage a lot of data.

Here is my code:

```
        <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
          ng-repeat="build in buildsRunning.builds.build | limitTo:totalDisplayed  track by build._id "
          ng-hide="build.hide"
          ng-class="{'running': build._running ,'block-green': build._status ==='SUCCESS','block-red': build._status==='FAILURE'}">
        <div class="title-container animate" >
            <p>{{::build._buildTypeId}}</p>
            <p class="running-on">Running on: <span class="agent">{{::build.agent._name}}</span></p>
            <p class="running-on">Version: <span class="agent">{{::build._number}}</span></p>
            <p class="running-on" ng-if="::build.user._name">Run by: {{::build.user._name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="update-container animate col-xs-12">
            <div class="progress progress-running">
                <div class="progress-bar "
                     role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{build._percentageComplete}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                     aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{build._percentageComplete}}%"
                     ng-class="{'progress-bar-success': build._percentageComplete > 5  ,'progress-bar-warning': build._percentageComplete <= 6}">
                        <span ng-if="build._percentageComplete > 5" class="sr-only"> {{build._percentageComplete}}% Completed
                            <p class="elapsed-time" ng-if="build._percentageComplete >= 50"> in : {{build.timeInfo}} Minutes</p>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Sorry for my English, if you do not understand me or need more information, please let me know

Comment: i don't think so that is because of `ng-class` it is because of `ng-repeat `directive, I think you are loading more than 1000 rows in `ng-repeat`

Comment: @pankajparkar Its possible, but Batarang  tells me that the ng-class is what takes more time to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pankajparkar pointed out, this will be caused by your rendering of, as you said,

> a lot of data.

---

However, best practice is to call a controller function which returns the classes:

```
<div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
      ng-repeat="build in buildsRunning.builds.build | limitTo:totalDisplayed  track by build._id "
      ng-hide="build.hide"
      ng-class="getClasses(build)">
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.getClasses = function(build) {
    // return whatever you like based on build object
}
```

Comment: Best practice? Why? What will happen if one of those build.required or somthing will change? Will the view still be updated?

Comment: Using the function as proposed, make it run a little faster, thanks

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Best practice because the build object is being accessed only once, plus, the data-binding is still active.

Comment: To  access only once, best practice wants you to us "one time binding", not a function.

Comment: I am talking about the object which is being passed to the `getClasses` function.